# How to click html tab by means vba internet automation

Tags: web-scraping

I need your support to click by means vba a tab with class x-tab-mod that load data in a html table. The tab is a li element inside ul element.
This is the html code of the tab i need to click :

```
<div class="x-tab-panel-header x-tab-panel-header-noborder x-unselectable" 

id="ext-gen203" style="width: 483px;">

<div class="x-tab-strip-wrap" id="ext-gen206">
<ul class="x-tab-strip x-tab-strip-top" id="ext-gen208">
<li class=" x-tab-mod x-tab-strip-active" id="id1">
<a class="x-tab-strip-close" onclick="return false;"></a>
<a class="x-tab-right" href="#" onclick="return false;">
<em class="x-tab-left"><span class="x-tab-strip-inner">
<span class="x-tab-strip-text ">tab</span></span></em></a></li>
<li class=" x-tab-mod" id="id2">
<a class="x-tab-strip-close" onclick="return false;"></a>
<a class="x-tab-right" href="#" onclick="return false;">
<em class="x-tab-left"><span class="x-tab-strip-inner">
<span class="x-tab-strip-text ">tab2</span></span></em></a></li>
<li class=" x-tab-mod" id="id3">
<a class="x-tab-strip-close" onclick="return false;"></a>
<a class="x-tab-right" href="#" onclick="return false;">
<em class="x-tab-left"><span class="x-tab-strip-inner">
<span class="x-tab-strip-text ">tab3</span></span></em></a></li>
<li class=" x-tab-mod" id="id4">
<a class="x-tab-strip-close" onclick="return false;"></a>
<a class="x-tab-right" href="#" onclick="return false;">
<em class="x-tab-left"><span class="x-tab-strip-inner">
<span class="x-tab-strip-text ">tab4</span></span></em></a></li>
<li class="x-tab-edge" id="ext-gen209"></li>
<div class="x-clear" id="ext-gen210"></div></ul></div>
<div class="x-tab-strip-spacer" id="ext-gen207"></div></div>
```

This is the vba code i used to try click on the tab that update data in a table:

```
Set tab = ie.document.getElementById("id4")
tab.Click
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend
```

but the click not fires the table updating

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Hi Dave is it more clear now ? Do you kniw how to solve this issue ?